# How to allow download url redirection only if user logged in Wordpress site?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect, htaccess, membership

I'm trying to allow url-redirection (from /dl urls) only if user is logged-in to wordpress site. Otherwise don't allow. However it went "page not found" when i click these urls with or without logging in.

I've used this .htaccess code on public-html level:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^.*wordpress_logged_in.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^dl/?$ https://external.com/directdownload- [L,R=301]
```

I expect to allow logged-in users to redirect to https://external.com/directdownload- links and don't allow redirection (and redirect them to login page) if they are not logged-in to wordpress. However when i click the links which are like https://www.example.com/dl/23434234/link.html both logged-in and not logged-in goes to "page not found". How to fix?

also tried below code and get the same file code when i click :'''`www.example.com/download.php/2n234n23/file.html`''' : '''`//load WP without theme support or hooks etc. define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);`'''

```
//load WP without theme support or hooks etc.
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-load.php'); //location of this file may be different 

if(get_current_user_id()){
    //user has valid WP login session
    header('Location: {location of perl script}');
}else{
    //user is not logged in
    header('Location: {location to boot them to}');
}
exit; //just because
```

How can i change above code to make it useful?

Answer (score 1):

An htaccess rule is evaluated **before** WP is called to get page content. So there is no variable you could use in an htaccess rule to check if a user is logged in.

Instead, I'd add to your functions.php file code that would check the `is_user_logged_in()` result. If not logged in, then use `wp_redirect()` to redirect to a login page. The `die()` is important after the wp_redirect so that the redirect will work properly.

Code would look something like this (not tested):

```
function check_user_logged_in() {
if (! is_user_logged_in()) {
   // not logged in, so redirect them
   wp_redirect("https://www.example.com/login-page");
   die();
   }
return;}
add_filter("init", "check_user_logged_in"); // fires the function on WP init
```

Of course, this should be placed in your Child Theme's functions.php file.

**Added 20 Jul 2020**

Corrected the code fragment to be `is_user_logged_in` - which I did speify correctly in the non-code portion of the answer. Thanks to @Frits for his eagle eye. (I did say it was untested code, so maybe that's my excuse....)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong - but is the function not supposed to be `is_user_logged_in()` instead of `user_logged_in()`?

Comment: Well, I did use the correct function name in the non-code section. I blame my keyboard. Fixed the code. Thanks @Frits